# Tsql Create Xml from table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table in SQL server and i would like to get the data in a xml format.

My table looks like

```
Year | Semester | Room | Professor
-----+----------+------+-----------    
2013 |    1     | 101  | Li
2013 |    1     | 102  | wang
2013 |    1     | 103  | Rob
2013 |    2     | 204  | jess
2013 |    2     | 205  | Mat
2014 |    1     | 104  | Li
2014 |    1     | 105  | wang
2014 |    1     | 106  | Rob
2014 |    2     | 206  | jess
2014 |    2     | 207  | Mat
```

I would like the Xml format like this:

```
<St>
  <Year id="2013">
    <Semester nb="1">
      <data>
        <Room>101</Room>
        <professor>Li</kwh>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>102</Room>
        <professor>wang</kwh>
      </data>
    </Semester>
    <Semester nb="2">
      <data>
        <Room>204</Room>
        <professor>jess</kwh>
      </data>
     </Semester>
  <Year>
 <Year id="2014">
    <Semester nb="1">
     ...
    </Semester>
    <Semester nb="2">
    ...
     </Semester>
  <Year>
</St>
```

For Now my code is:

```
SELECT 
    Year as "@id", 
    Semester as "Semester /@nb", 
    Room as "Semester/data/Room", 
    Professor as "Semester/data/Professor " 
FROM 
    checking
FOR XML Path ('Year'), root ('St')
```

Which give me this xml:

```
<St>   
<Year id="2013">
<Semester nb="1">
 <data>
        <Room>101</Room>
        <Professor>Li</Professor>
     </data>
   </Semester>   </Year>   <Year id="2013">
    <Semester nb="1">
      <data>
        <Room>102</Room>
        <Professor>wang</Professor>
    </data>
    </Semester>   </Year>   <Year id="2013">
   <Semester nb="1">
     <data>
       <Room>103</Room>
      <Professor>rob</Professor>
     </data>
    </Semester>   
</Year>
 ... 
</St>
```

I am very close to the solution but can't find how to group it by year and semester.

I try group by and order by but none of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use group by and correlated subqueries.

```sql
declare @T table
(
  Year int,
  Semester int,
  Room int,
  Professor varchar(10)
);

insert into @T values
(2013, 1, 101, 'Li  '),
(2013, 1, 102, 'wang'),
(2013, 1, 103, 'Rob '),
(2013, 2, 204, 'jess'),
(2013, 2, 205, 'Mat '),
(2014, 1, 104, 'Li  '),
(2014, 1, 105, 'wang'),
(2014, 1, 106, 'Rob '),
(2014, 2, 206, 'jess'),
(2014, 2, 207, 'Mat ');

select T1.Year as [@id],
       (
       select T2.Semester as [@nb],
              (
              select T3.Room,
                     T3.Professor
              from @T as T3
              where T3.Year = T2.Year and
                    T3.Semester = T2.Semester
              for xml path('data'), type
              )
       from @T as T2
       where T1.Year = T2.Year
       group by T2.Semester, T2.Year
       for xml path('Semester'), type
       )
from @T as T1
group by T1.Year
for xml path('Year'), root('St');
```

Result:

```xml
<St>
  <Year id="2013">
    <Semester nb="1">
      <data>
        <Room>101</Room>
        <Professor>Li  </Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>102</Room>
        <Professor>wang</Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>103</Room>
        <Professor>Rob </Professor>
      </data>
    </Semester>
    <Semester nb="2">
      <data>
        <Room>204</Room>
        <Professor>jess</Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>205</Room>
        <Professor>Mat </Professor>
      </data>
    </Semester>
  </Year>
  <Year id="2014">
    <Semester nb="1">
      <data>
        <Room>104</Room>
        <Professor>Li  </Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>105</Room>
        <Professor>wang</Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>106</Room>
        <Professor>Rob </Professor>
      </data>
    </Semester>
    <Semester nb="2">
      <data>
        <Room>206</Room>
        <Professor>jess</Professor>
      </data>
      <data>
        <Room>207</Room>
        <Professor>Mat </Professor>
      </data>
    </Semester>
  </Year>
</St>
```

Comment: I try it and i get this error:
Column '@T.Year' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @usertfwr You probably forgot to group by on `T2.Year` in the second sub-query. Works fine here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/284123/build-xml

Comment: true, it works if i declare the table like in the example but not if i use the one already create in my database. i don't know why

Comment: @user update the question with the query that does not work for you.

Comment: i change my table and now it works thanks for your help!